# opening a bitcoin exchange with AlphaPoint

Tags: exchanges

I am thinking about opening a Bitcoin exchange. While reading questions here about opening a Bitcoin exchange business, I saw a post mention AlphaPoint, a company, which, from what I understood, helps people who want to open a Bitcoin exchange business. I then even read on AlphaPoint's LinkedIn page:

> Full system to run a digital asset exchange. Fully hosted options
>   available. **Customize and launch your own digital currency and/or
>   Bitcoin exchange in less than 20 days with AlphaPoint**.

From what I saw on other forums, it look like it's a serious company and not some scam. But it still sounds a bit fishy to me because I don't understand the basics of what is all about and what is the deal here.

What would AlphaPoint expect someone who wants to open a Bitcoin exchange to do with their service? Bitcoin exchanges are usually automatic, right? So, if they provide all the tech and equipment, why do they need customers who want to open a Bitcoin exchange business? Do they expect the customers to be experts in servers and/or programming?

I know it's maybe a question that I should ask on the AlphaPoint site, but I feel more comfortable to know that other people see that it is a legit deal that makes sense.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a former client of theirs on this site. That said, what they're offering is at least technically feasible.

Comment: The customer presumably has to put up whatever capital is needed to get the exchange started, handle any registration required by their local law, and assume legal liability in the event that the exchange goes bust.